# Cannot populate a Ext GridPanel through GeoExt WMSCapabilitiesStore

Tags: geoserver, wms, geoext, boundless-suite

I've been working through a few tutorial/starter map samples on the [OpenGeo](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/) and [GeoExt](http://www.geoext.org/tutorials/index.html) websites and have come upon a problem I cannot solve. I'm trying to load a list of layers from my GeoServer into a GridPanel using [GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore](http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/data/WMSCapabilitiesStore.html). No matter what I try, I cannot get anything to show in the GridPanel. I thought I had cross domain issues at first, but the problem persists even when the webpage and the GeoServer data are on the same server.

Here's a link to my very barren looking web map: http://24.105.210.45/OpenGeoGeoExtMap1.html.

Here's the JavaScript that's supposed to access the wms and load the layer list:

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    title: "Available WMS Layers",
    region: "north",
    height: 150,
    viewConfig: {forceFit: true},
    store: new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
        url: "http://24.105.210.45:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities",
        autoLoad: true
        }),
        columns: [
            {header: "Name", dataIndex: "name", sortable: true},
            {header: "Title", dataIndex: "title", sortable: true},
            {header: "Abstract", dataIndex: "abstract"}
            ],
```

Any help with this, or just ideas of where to look next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get a 404 not found from http://24.105.210.45/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: The full URL to the wms would be: http://24.105.210.45:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: http://24.105.210.45/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities isn't returning a capabilities file - which is what your page is asking for.

Comment: iant - see my comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different port numbers are considered as different domains - even if the rest of the URL is the same. So if your main site is running on:

```
http://24.105.210.45:80
```

You would need a proxy to access:

```
http://24.105.210.45:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities
```

So the proxy FAQ below applies in your case:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost

Why can't you  run both your web application and Geoserver on the same port?

**Update:**

You can also get around the same domain policy using YQL - http://geographika.co.uk/accessing-cross-domain-data-with-yql

Comment: I'm running GeoServer and IIS 7.5. Neither will let me set their port to the others port.

Comment: @don You'll need a proxy, host the web site with GeoServer (on Apache), or you could try a URL rewrite approach - http://serverfault.com/questions/216004/iis-7-url-rewrite-to-geoserver-running-on-apache

Comment: Thanks geographika - I'm struggling with understanding how proxies work and how to set them up, and with the URL rewrite option. I'm thinking it might be easier to just move everything on to Apache.

Comment: Unless you are using .NET in your web application, moving to Apache would be easier. If you need a proxy have a look at http://geographika.co.uk/a-proxy-for-iis-and-net - I think this should work with ports