# GeoExt and Mapserver

Tags: mapserver, geoext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot populate a Ext GridPanel through GeoExt WMSCapabilitiesStore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/cannot-populate-a-ext-gridpanel-through-geoext-wmscapabilitiesstore)

I'm using Mapserver + GeoExt, but i can't not recive any data from this request, any one know how to use that?

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    title: "Availables WMS Layers",
                    renderTo: document.body, 
                    width: 800,
                    height: 150,
                    viewConfig: {forceFit: true},
                    store: new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
                        url: "http://localhost:8085/fcgi-bin/wms.exe?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1",
                        autoLoad: true
                    }),
                    columns: [
                        {header: "Name", dataIndex: "name", sortable: true}
                    ]
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your http://localhost:8085/fcgi-bin/wms.exe?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1 link is working, then this is likely to be a cross-domain issue:

See answer at [Cannot populate a Ext GridPanel through GeoExt WMSCapabilitiesStore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/cannot-populate-a-ext-gridpanel-through-geoext-wmscapabilitiesstore)

Comment: This is a diferent question, because i'm using MapSever, in this example the answer is about GeoServer.

Comment: It's the same problem. You can't load data from a different URL or port number in a browser. You need a proxy, or run on the same port.

Comment: OK! 

In my example using this address: http://localhost:8085/fcgi-bin/wms.exe

How can i define this proxy? Some thing like that? I do not have a file named "proxy.cgi".

OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/fcgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

Comment: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost

Comment: I take a look at proxy.cgi configuration, but i'm work with Windows and Apache, so in this way, i'll need to configure and install python!?

Comment: http://geographika.co.uk/a-proxy-for-iis-and-net

Comment: Ok! I configure this proxy, and i using in this way:

OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "http://localhost:8085/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";

But can't retrive any information use the code:

store: new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
      url: "http://localhost:8085/cgi-bin/wms.exe?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1",
      autoLoad: true
     })