# GeoExt Popup is blank

Tags: geoserver, geoext

I am doing the sample example from [OpenGeo WorkShop](http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/stores/getfeatureinfo.html). It's about creating simple popup. I get popup but with blank no feature information? I am using geoserver with geoext.

[image]

```
controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({              
                autoActivate: true,
                infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
                maxFeatures: 3,
                eventListeners: {
                    "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {
                        alert(e.xy);
                        var items = [];
                        Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {
                            items.push({
                                xtype: "propertygrid",
                                title: feature.fid,
                                source: feature.attributes
                            });
                        });
                        new GeoExt.Popup({
                            title: "Info",
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                            layout: "accordion",
                            map: app.mapPanel,
                            location: e.xy,
                            maximizable: true,
                            collapsible: true,
                            items: items 
                        }).show();
                    }
                }
            }));
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your HTML file? Maybe on pastebin or something similar? http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @R.K. my code at pastebin http://pastebin.com/apSMeK2t

Comment: A bit busy here. Btw, did the medford layer load? Because I don't see the Medford layer on your screenshot.

Comment: Were you able to successfully load the medford data before you tried your own?

Comment: @R.K. yes all layers load successfully

Comment: Did the popup work then, too? Got a copy of the file that worked? I wanna do a diff.

Comment: @R.K. well I changed the code from same example :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2417/discussion-between-r-k-and-kitex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The problem was due to two server running at different ports being considered as separate domains. Tomcat being deployed at one port  and geoserver at other port. This link here in [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/cannot-populate-a-ext-gridpanel-through-geoext-wmscapabilitiesstore) explains more.

Comment: You finally got it to work then?

Comment: @R.K. Yes and Thank you :) for you help well simple mistake took my days of sleep

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to start over. You could use the [OpenGeo GeoExt workshop files](http://files.opengeo.org/workshopmaterials/gx_workshop.zip). Should be easier than starting from scratch. Good luck. Oh and use version control next time.